# Resource Not Found Error, when convert text to number

Tags: android, parseint

I tried following code in eclipse to develop simple 2 value addition, but getting error on Button click....

## Please Help me on this.

public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

```
EditText etval1, etval2;
Button btnclick;
TextView tvans;
Integer v1 = 0, v2 = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    etval1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    etval2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btnclick=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tvans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btnclick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v1=Integer.parseInt(etval1.getText().toString());
            v2=Integer.parseInt(etval2.getText().toString());
            //v1=100; v2=200;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click", 3000).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (v1+v2), 1000).show();
           // getting error in above line.........
            //tvans.setText( etval1.getText().toString() );
            tvans.setText(v1+v2);
          // getting error in above line.........
        }
    });
}
```

## }

I am getting error, "Resource Not Found" in Log Cat, when Using Integer.parseInt() to convert value. Guide mo on this.

Comment: post logcat, because Integer.parseInt() can't give you "Resource not found".

Comment: Why Integer why not int. also use `String.valueOf(int)` setText takes characterSequence. You have one that takes `int` but that is not what you need. The same for `Toast`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a mistake on this line:

```
tvans.setText(v1+v2);
```

You are passing an `int` to the `setText` method. This has to be used to pass as parameter the Id of a string defined in the resource. In your case, the corresponding Id does not exist. That's why you get the *Resources Not Found*.

Here you want to set the sum of your `int`s as text, you have to do this:

```
tvans.setText(v1+v2+"");
```

For more information, take a look at the [different uses](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int%20resid)) of setText().

Comment: Beat me to it :P Made this mistake starting out myself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is coming from this line, `tvans.setText(v1+v2);`.

Instead of setting the `TextView` to the number, it is attempting to find a resource with the id value of `v1+v2`.

Use `tvans.setText(Integer.toString(v1+v2));`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

but i did minor changes as following

tvans.setText(" "+**(v1+v2)**);

- variables withing parenthesis

Comment: if parenthesis not added then it will like 78, instead of 7+8=15

Comment: Have you tested without the parenthesis? Because I just tried the following code and it prints 3, not 12: `int a = 1; int b = 2; System.out.println(a+b+"");`

Comment: Yes, got the answer, in between inverted comma, i added one space tvans.setText(v1+v2+" ");   that concates values, but without space tvans.setText(v1+v2+"");  got the answer. Once again thanks